# I want to count subscription days

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I want to count subscription days
i tried using timedelta() but I need to skip Thursday while calculating,
its a 26 day subscription but no delivery on Thursday

```py
started = datetime.date(2022 , 5 , 22 )
subscription  = datetime.timedelta(26)

print( started+subscription )
```

Comment: If the code you have shown uses the same `timedelta` that everyone has, `timedelta(26)` creates a timedelta object representing 26 days, and it has no way of knowing you want to skip Thursdays. Maybe you could come up with some math to figure out how many Thursdays (hint: Thursday-Thursday is 7 days) are in your window, and then add that number of days to your answer to get the real answer?

Answer (score 0):

To count (increment daily) or to calculate ? Calculation is a calendar problem - you need to calculate the number of exclusion days (Thursdays's).

Your case is easy since there is always exactly 4 Thursdays in any 26-day calendar span.

Answer (score -1):

Both datetime.date and datetime.datetime objects have a today method that return respectively a Date and a Datetime object.

Which both have a weekday and isoweekday methods. weekday count from Monday = 0, while isoweekday count from Monday = 1:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
if date.today().weekday() == 0:
    # it is Monday
if datetime.today().isoweekday() == 1:
   # it is Monday
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I is useful to eliminate the Thursdays from the date range from the two dates and calculate date.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).